# Simplifying an arithmetic expression in Python

Tags: python, math, sympy

I'm trying to write a python code on simplifying a given expression (in order to solve a non-homogeneous linear diophantine equation.) For example, given the input:

```
7x+13y = 1
```

the code will return

```
1=7-(1*(13-(1*7))
```

I want to be able to simplify the right hand side of the output such that it is expressed only in terms of the coefficients of the input. In this case:

```
1=7-((1*13)+(1*-(1*7))
1=7-(1*13)-(-1*7)
1=(2*7)+(-1*13)
```

so

```
1=(2*7)+(-1*13)
```

is the final result (I can extract the 2 and -1, multiply in by the constant of the original input to receive an integer solution set for x and y.)

I tried looking and implementing Sympy simplify, however none of them provided any aid in the aforementioned task. Either they returned the original output or an error message.

Comment: Given the input, how, on paper, would you find that output?

Comment: The extended Euclidean algorithm (substitution with the euclidean algorithm for gcf).

Comment: You could implement the extended Euclidean algorithm directly as a python function that returns the triple `(g, x, y)`. Then you don't need to simplify any arithmetic expressions and you can write directly `return f'{g} = {x} * 7 + {y} * 13'`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are looking for the extended Euclidean algorithm which SymPy provides as `gcdex`:

```
In [1]: from sympy import gcdex

In [2]: gcdex(7,13)
Out[2]: (2, -1, 1)
```